# 2001 bmw 325ci auto transmission

Tags: automatic-transmission, bmw

I have a 2001 BMW 325ci with an auto transmission. My problem is that when I put it in gear it only goes in reverse but not forward. In forward it only revs up. 
My engine light is on and says my cam and crankshaft sensors are bad, do you guys think the problems are related?
I read in a forum that when a sensor is bad the transmission goes into some type of safe mode but they dont specify which sensor. if you have any idea of the problem please let me know 
i want to avoid a rebuild.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: That sort of 'safe mode' is usually called Limp mode. Basically it limits the gears and therefor speed (If I'm not mistaken) so the engine couldn't be damaged (even more). I'd definitely get those sensors checked if they are reading something when they shouldn't and vica versa. Sensors are usually way cheaper than other parts. I'd get them replaced and see if the problem still persists.